# How to programatically expand nodes of ColumnTree in Smartgwt?

Tags: java, tree, smartgwt

I have a ComboBoxItem which works as a search box where its picklist is, for now, items of a ColumnTree. On selecting one of the picklist's items which returns a ListGridRecord, I want to expand that specific node in the ColumnTree programmatically. Please note that I have also set

```
ColumnTree.setShowMultipleColumns(false);
```

I also used the following code snippet, but no luck so far:

```
TreeNode treeNode = columnTree.getData().find("EmployeeId", 264);
columnTree.selectRecord(treeNode);
```

I am using the source code available here:

[ColumnTree example](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_miller_columns)

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: The example you've shared already works the way you've mentioned. When you select a node, it gets expanded. What's the issue?

Comment: doesn't work when setShowMultipleColumns() is set to false.